# Can't make Wallch (wallpaper changer) show up in Loki, even though it's running

Tags: applications, desktop, wallpaper

I have installed Wallch wallpaper changerin Loki. Used it on Luna but in Loki It appears to be running but the desktop background remains.So how to turn off the default wallpaper and allow wallch to show? I have Loki running, very nice, and really want my wallpaper slideshow. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't resolve the Wallch issue, but loaded Variety and it does the job.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Wallch (http://melloristudio.com/wallch/) is not supposed to work on elementary OS. You might want to file a feature request at https://bugs.launchpad.net/wallpaper-changer